# transpose column values as appending columns with values into a single record

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have submission rows like this in table #1

| id | cmpID | assigned |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4920 | 1 | agent1 |
| 4921 | 2 | agent4 |
| 4922 | 1 | agent4 |

| 4923 | 2 | agent1
| 4924 | 3 | agent1
| 4925 | 3 | agent4

and for every unique row id, there are appending related child records in another table.

| meta_id | parent_id | meta_name | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9123 | 4920 | first_name | john |
| 9124 | 4920 | last_name | doe |
| 9125 | 4920 | email | john.doe1@gmail.com |
| 9126 | 4920 | salutation | mr |
| 9127 | 4922 | first_name | jack |
| 9128 | 4922 | last_name | smith |
| 9129 | 4922 | email | jack.smith2@msn.com |
| 9130 | 4922 | salutation | mr |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I'm trying to achieve the following query results, for example get rows from a specific cmpID ie. 1, with the appended columns based on the meta_names from another table

| id | cmpID | assigned | first_name | last_name | email | salutation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4920 | 1 | agent1 | john | doe | john.doe1@gmail.com | mr |
| 4922 | 1 | agent4 | jack | smith | jack.smith2@msn.com | mr |

Is there a way without using dynamic sql queries ie. @sql to achieve this?

Tried to GROUP_CONCAT and LEFT JOIN to get the values of the related child rows into single result row but this is not what I'm looking for.

Appreciate any advise and solutions here.